# Bidirectional bubble sort proof

Tags: python, algorithm, bubble-sort

I'm taking an intro to algorithms course. As a part of a home exercise I need to prove that a given bidirectional bubble sort algorithm is correct.
We have to following algorithm (implemented in python):

```
def bidirectional_bubble_sort(a):
left = -1
right = len(a)
while left < right:
    swap = False
    left += 1
    right -= 1
    for i in xrange(left, right):
        if a[i] > a[i + 1]:
            t = a[i]
            a[i] = a[i + 1]
            a[i + 1] = t
            swap = True
    if not swap:
        return
    else:
        swap = False
    for i in xrange(right - 1, left - 1, -1):
        if a[i] > a[i + 1]:
            t = a[i]
            a[i] = a[i + 1]
            a[i + 1] = t
            swap = True
    if not swap:
        return
```

I'm a bit confused by the main loop condition. Does the algorithm ever gets to the point where left>=right (**before** exiting at one of the inner return statements)?

Comment: Yup. It does. `left` is being incremented and `right` is being decremented, so eventually left has to be greater than right.

Answer (score 1):

```
while left < right:
    swap = False
    left += 1
    right -= 1
```

`left` and `right` are initialized as left-most and right-most index of the array and for each iteration its going towards right and left direction unconditionally - no matter what will happen on next two loops. So obviously `left >= right` will happen and exit the loop.

For array of even length, `left > right` and for array of odd length, `left == right` will be reached and exit the loop.

Debug and you will get it yourself.

## Edit

> I need to prove that a given bidirectional bubble sort algorithm is
>   correct

Can you try this snippet. It seems above implementation is not correct.

```
def bidirectional_bubble_sort(a):
    left = -1
    right = len(a)
    while left < right:
        swap = False
        left += 1
        right -= 1
        for i in xrange(left, right):
            if a[i] > a[i + 1]:
                t = a[i]
                a[i] = a[i + 1]
                a[i + 1] = t
                swap = True
        if not swap:
            return
        else:
            swap = False
        for i in xrange(right, left, -1):
            if a[i] < a[i - 1]:
                t = a[i]
                a[i] = a[i - 1]
                a[i - 1] = t
                swap = True
        if not swap:
            return
```

Comment: True, but I can't figure out a case where we don't exit the loop at one of the swaps checks ("if not swap")

Comment: because there is no such case. Look at those loops, whatever swaps happens or not, i will be incremented and exit the loop for sure.

Comment: Use pen and paper to simulate 2/3 testcases and use debugger to see what happens in each iteration.

Comment: I understand the loop is finite. My problem is explaining the left < right part.

Comment: Are you hesitated with when this `if not swap: return` will happen?

Comment: Yes. I did try debugging and running some test cases, but I always ended at `if not swap: return`

Comment: Edited original question to better explain my problem.

Comment: As mentioned in the original post, the algorithm was given to us. I double checked and the second inner loop is implemented correctly